# Get string from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im looking for an easy way to extract `filename1.npy` from following numpy array `test`:

```
array([['filename1.npy'],
       ['filename2.npy'],
       ['filename3.npy']],
      dtype=object)
```

I can easily do: `str(test[1])` but then I still have those brackets around it `['filename1.npy']`. Though, I just want the name to insert it into `np.load(path+'filename1.npy')`

Comment: `test[0][0]? ` That should work

Comment: Read up on accessing [nested lists](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/lists.html#nested-lists).

Comment: Ah I see, perfect. I want to use it, for iteration, so then it becomes: ```for i in range(3): name= test[i] x = name[0]```

Comment: it's better to use `os.path.join(path, 'filename1.npy')`

Comment: If yoy are loading `npy` files yoh should become familiar with array basics, like dtype, shape, and indexing. Don't skip the numpy intro docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, for the quick response:

`test[0][0]`

works fine to get filename1.npy.

To loop through all names, I now use:

```
for index in range(3):
    name = test[index]
    name = name[0]

    # load single file
    single_file = np.load(os.path.join(path,name))
```

Comment: `test[0,0]` is the best way of indexing a 2d array like this.